# How can I check (control) a .avi format video file in specific file, is it over 0KB and readable?

Tags: c++, file, opencv, readable

How can I check (control) a .avi format video file in specific file, is it over 0KB and readable?

for example;
I have a video recorder Button, and I click on it, then my function record 1 minute and save into file as test.avi (this function in a while(true){} statement)

in while(true)

save as test.avi

save as test2.avi
.

.

.

save as test8.avi

So how can I check this test.avi and all other videofiles, if(test.avi is not 0KB and readable), What should I do?

```
int main(void) {

    while (true)
    {
        //Check if test.avi ready
        if (test.avi is not 0KB and readable)
        {
            doSomeStuff01();

        }
        /* Check one more Time
        else
        {

        }*/
        //Check if test2.avi ready
        if (test2.avi is not 0KB and readable)
        {
            doSomeStuff02();
        }
        /* Check one more Time
        else
        {

        }*/
        //Check if test3.avi ready
        if (test3.avi is not 0KB and readable)
        {
            doSomeStuff03();
        }
        /* Check one more Time
        else
        {

        }*/
        //Check if test4.avi ready
        if (test4.avi is not 0KB and readable)
        {
            doSomeStuff04();
        }
        /* Check one more Time
        else
        {

        }*/
        //Check if test5.avi ready
        if (test5.avi is not 0KB and readable)
        {
            doSomeStuff05();
        }
        /* Check one more Time
        else
        {

        }*/
        //Check if test6.avi ready
        if (test6.avi is not 0KB and readable)
        {
            doSomeStuff06();
        }
        /* Check one more Time
        else
        {

        }*/
        //Check if test7.avi ready
        if (test7.avi is not 0KB and readable)
        {
            doSomeStuff07();
        }
        /* Check one more Time
        else
        {

        }*/
        //Check if test8.avi ready
        if (test8.avi is not 0KB and readable)
        {
            doSomeStuff08();
        }
        /* Check one more Time
        else
        {

        }*/

    }


    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better solutions for this but here's an idea:

1. Create a VideoCapture and check if you can open the .avi file, otherwise catch an exception; http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html
2. If the video is 0 kB = no frames:

`if(frame.empty()){
   cout << "frame is empty" << endl;
}`